# Include js files in Custom Wordpress Plugin

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I'm trying to develop my own Wordpress Plugin, but somehow I can't include javascript files in it. Before I concidered to ask this question here, i've done a lot of research, but none of it was fixing my problem. I've read a lot about wp_register_script() and wp_enqueue_script(), and also that I don't have to include both, so I decided to only use wp_enqueue_script().

The javascript file is located in wp-content/snappy-list-plugin/js/public/snappy-wordpress-plugin.js, and the index file is located in wp-content/snappy-list-plugin/snappy-wordpress-plugin.php.

In the snappy-wordpress-plugin.php file I have:

```
function mslb_public_scripts(){

wp_enqueue_script('custom_js', plugins_url( '/snappy-list-plugin/js/public/snappy-wordpress-plugin.js', __FILE__ ), array('jquery'), '', true);

}
```

which seems to be oke, but it doesn't include the file.

On top of the file I have:

`add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'mslb_public_scripts');`

Can somebody help me with this?!

I tried to add wp_register_script(), but it doesn't work

```
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'mslb_public_scripts');

function mslb_public_scripts(){

    wp_enqueue_script('custom_js', plugins_url( '/snappy-list-plugin/js/public/snappy-wordpress-plugin.js', __FILE__ ), array('jquery'), '', true);

}
```

snappy-wordpress-plugin.js file:

````
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    var wpajax_url = document.location.protocol + '//' +  document.location.host + '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php';

    var email_capture_url = wpajax_url += '?action=swp_save_subscription';

    $('form.swp_form').bind('submit', function(){

        $form = $(this); 

        var form_data = $form.serialize(); 

        $.ajax({
            'method'    : 'post', 
            'url'       : email_capture_url,
            'data'      : form_data,
            'dataType'  : 'json',
            'cache'     : false,
            'success'   : function( data, textStatus){
                if(data.status == 1){
                    $form[0].reset(); 
                    alert(data.message);
                } else {
                    var msg = data.message + '\r' + data.error + '\r';
                    $.each(data.error, function(key, value){
                        msg += '\r';
                        msg += ' - ' + value;
                    });
                    alert( msg );
                }
            }, 
            'error'  : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){

            } 
        });

        //stop the form from submitting normally

        return false; 

    });

});```
````

Answer (score 3):

The right action is `wp_enqueue_scripts`

```
 add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'mslb_public_scripts');

 function mslb_public_scripts(){
   wp_register_script('custom_js', plugins_url('/js/public/snappy-wordpress-plugin.js',__FILE__ ), array('jquery'), '', true);
   wp_enqueue_script('custom_js');
 }
```